# Poor performance of envoy vs when we test inside the container

Tags: benchmarking, envoyproxy

We have the following envoy configuration:

```yaml
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901

static_resources:
  listeners:

  ################################################################################
  # HTTP listeners
  ################################################################################
  - name: http_listener
    address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 80
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          http_protocol_options:
            accept_http_10: true
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          access_log:
          - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          route_config:
            name: services_route
            virtual_hosts:
            # example.com
            - name: example.com
              domains: ["example.com"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                
                route: { cluster: example_cluster }
    

  ################################################################################
  # Clusters
  ################################################################################
  clusters:

  # Cluster: example
  - name: example_cluster
    type: LOGICAL_DNS
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: example_cluster
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: example
                port_value: 3000
```

When we bench mark the our *example* component inside the server (not inside the container) where the connection gets passed through the envoy proxy we see the following result:

```
$ ab -n1000 -c10 http://example.com/callback/eaa8d66b-b169-42cd-98c2-6c654f1d9175
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1843412 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
Benchmarking vitatrk.com (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests

Server Software:        cloudflare
Server Hostname:        example.com
Server Port:            80
Document Path:          /callback/eaa8d66b-b169-42cd-98c2-6c654f1d9175
Document Length:        0 bytes
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   13.514 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      1000
Total transferred:      769800 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    74.00 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       135.144 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       13.514 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          55.63 [Kbytes/sec] received
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        8   10   0.8     10      15
Processing:    26  124 105.5     44     292
Waiting:       26   37   8.1     36      98
Total:         34  134 105.5     55     302
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     55
  66%    253
  75%    258
  80%    261
  90%    267
  95%    271
  98%    277
  99%    282
 100%    302 (longest request)
```

But when we run the same test INSIDE the container itself we see the following result:

```
root@74bc950be281:/dist# ab -n1000 -c10 http://0:3000/callback/eaa8d66b-b169-42cd-98c2-6c654f1d9175
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1843412 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/
Benchmarking 0 (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Completed 600 requests
Completed 700 requests
Completed 800 requests
Completed 900 requests
Completed 1000 requests
Finished 1000 requests

Server Software:        
Server Hostname:        0
Server Port:            3000
Document Path:          /callback/eaa8d66b-b169-42cd-98c2-6c654f1d9175
Document Length:        0 bytes
Concurrency Level:      10
Time taken for tests:   2.120 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Non-2xx responses:      1000
Total transferred:      255000 bytes
HTML transferred:       0 bytes
Requests per second:    471.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       21.203 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       2.120 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          117.44 [Kbytes/sec] received
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.0      0       1
Processing:     5   21   6.5     20      57
Waiting:        4   21   6.5     20      57
Total:          5   21   6.5     20      57
Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     20
  66%     23
  75%     25
  80%     26
  90%     30
  95%     34
  98%     38
  99%     41
 100%     57 (longest request)
```

As you can see both are trying to connect through HTTP protocol and we run only 1 instance of the container but when we have the envoy as the middleware to proxy the traffic to our container we have `74 RPS` (Request Per Second) throughput but when we perform the same test inside the container we have `471 RPS` which is almost 7 times faster.
Also, we can see the *mean* processing time when we test with envoy as middleware is `124ms` but when we perform the test inside the container it's `21ms` obviously envoy adds `~100ms` to the processing time.

The envoy version we use: `v1.20.1`

I wonder to know if we are doing something wrong in the envoy's configuration or not. why does envoy as middleware slows down the throughput? because we ran both tests in the same condition, one instance, HTTP protocol, same testing configuration! why we observe such a behaviour?

Comment: Isn't it network latency introduced when you call your envoy? I can see `ab -n1000 -c10 http://example.com/` in the first example, so it looks like you're calling envoy from another host, and localhost in your second example. Could you reproduce the same results when calling `localhost:80` **from the container** in a first bench, and `localhost:3000` in a second bench?

Comment: @norbjd There is no `localhost:80` there is only one `localhost:3000` which was performed inside the container, and `http://example.com` was performed in the same server that envoy was deployed!

Comment: Hm, your `http_listener` seems to be listening on port `80` (`socket_address.port_value`), and `http://example.com` probably points to that port. I think that even if you're on the same server, if you're querying an external address `http://example.com` your traffic is going through Internet instead of just staying on your server (unless than `example.com` is a local address).

Comment: @norbjd Even if we say the request goes through the internet, that shouldn't introduce `~100ms` processing time overhead, that cause connecting time to increase :/

Comment: Could you connect directly to your Envoy (localhost) from your server just to be sure that the performance issue comes from Envoy?

Comment: @norbjd Yes, I performed `ab -n1000 -c10 http://0:9901/` inside the server and it had a high throughput

Comment: 9901 is the admin port, did you mean :80 ?

Comment: @norbjd when I perform the `curl http://0:80` it returns NOT FOUND as it doesn't know what to do with the incoming request (due to the fact it require a host name to redirect the traffic to its container) and when I performed `ab -n1000 -c10 http://0:80/` it showed very low throughput: 9 RPS! with average processing time of almost 1 second!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247277/discussion-between-norbjd-and-dariush).